# Certbot on Debian 11 - notification?

Tags: linux, debian, certbot

This is my first post here. Recently I have changed my server. Now I am using Debian 11 and can't figure out how to setup certbot to behave like previous version.

Renewal of certs works like a charm. The strange thig was that certbot installed by snapd did not setup auto renewal or at least there was now cron.d, cronatab and also systemctl timres entries. So I put simple crontab: certbot renew >> /var/log/logfile.

On my previous server when it was run I received meesages like that:

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Cert not yet due for renewal

and when it was renewed there was also information. Now in the latest version of certbot 1.22.0 I got email only saying that certbot was run: "Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log"

Is there any way to change this to tell that certs are not renewed? And the second question is do I need to restart apache server after such cronjob to install new certs?

Comment: Your question is not about programming, so off-topic in this site. Maybe Unix and Linux stack exchange (one sister site from us, links on top tight icon) is more relevant. But "snapd" is probably not Debian, so the tag is also wrong. Probably now cerbot is writing to stderr, so you should redirect stderr to the log.

Comment: Good to now, sorry. I have read lots of hints on this site but didnt now it has more forums. Thanks.